# How to relate the user table with the fboauth table to show up who's logged in through fb?

Tags: social-network

I have created a view which shows up the user details like username, email, active(user), accepted challenges in a tabular format. Now i want to include a column to it which shows up the users who uses their fb account to login to the website.I have used fboauth module to allow users to login to the website through their fb account and i am unable to add a relationship which relates the users table and the fboauth table. Can anyone suggest me a way to resolve this?

I am using drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1. First is that you can add a field to the USER, named as fb_user(Keep the default value as "no"). Now look into the fbouth code where a user is being created. Write a sql query there using Database API to update the field fb_user as "yes". Now you can easily add the field in views to find out FB users.
2. Create a custom module. Inside that write a hooks_views_query_alter:-https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7
   [Custom query in Views?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73/custom-query-in-views)