# How to download Database results as PDF or in EXCEL

Tags: database, files

I have a custom query to fetch the details from database (oracle). The results are generating properly as expected. Now i need to download these results either a PDF or an EXCEL file. Any way to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Views PDF](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_pdf) module you can output a View as a PDF.

> With this module you can output a view as a PDF document. Each field of the view can be placed on the PDF page directly in the administration interface. Therefore a new display called "PDF" is added.

Since you have your custom query, by [Custom query in Views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73/custom-query-in-views) you can alter the results of the View. The print the output of view is PDF using the above module.

---

**UPDATE**

Since you created a node and fetch database result via that node you must use [Printer, email and PDF versions](https://www.drupal.org/project/print) module

> This module allows you to generate the following printer-friendly versions of any node:
>
> - Printer-friendly version (webpage format) (at www.example.com/print/nid)
> - ***PDF version (at www.example.com/printpdf/nid)***
> - EPUB version (at www.example.com/printepub/nid)
> - Send by email (at www.example.com/printmail/nid)

where nid is the node id of content to render.

so by `www.example.com/printpdf/nid` you can create a  PDF output of the node.

Comment: Thanks @Drupalist. Custom query is implemented without any views. I Created a node and added a template file with its node id. There i added my custom query to fetch details from database. Do i can download  these results.?

Comment: You welcome, I updated the answer

Comment: Is there any way to print entire result without pagination?

Comment: What do you mean? explain a bit more

Comment: I added a custom pagination function to load 10 results per page. Do this modules print the entire results or only 10 results?.

Comment: It prints what comes to the screen, to print the content in other pages, use `pdf_using_mpdf` APIs

Answer (score 1):

Using these modules you can do that

[views_export_xls](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_export_xls)

> Simple module that allows to export Views data to Excel (xls). Uses
>   php-excel class with UTF8 support.

[views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)

> - You like the default front page view, but you find you want to sort    it differently.
> - You like the default taxonomy/term view, but you find you want to    sort it differently; for example, alphabetically.
> - You use /tracker, but you want to restrict it to posts of a certain    type.
> - You like the idea of the 'article' module, but it doesn't display    articles the way you like.
> - You want a way to display a block with the 5 most recent posts of    some particular type.
> - You want to provide 'unread forum posts'.
> - You want a monthly archive similar to the typical Movable    Type/Wordpress archives that displays a link to the in the form of
>     "Month, YYYY (X)" where X is the number of posts that month, and
>     displays them in a block. The links lead to a simple list of posts
>     for that month.
>
> Views can do a lot more than that, but those are some of the obvious
>   uses of Views.

[views_data_export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export)

> This module is designed to provide a way to export large amounts of
>   data from views. It provides a display plugin that can rendered
>   progressively in a batch. Style plugins are included that support
>   exporting in the following types:
>
> - CSV
> - Microsoft XLS
> - Microsoft DOC
> - Basic TXT
> - XML.

[Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena)

> The current version allows you to create reports using SQL from
>   Drupal, or using data stored in XML files.
>
> It comes bundled with a couple of sample reports that will both
>   demonstrate how reports are created, and provide useful information on
>   your existing Drupal site.
>
> Some key features include:
>
> - Create custom reports from your Drupal database.
> - Create custom reports against PDO supported database (SQLite, MySQL,    MS SQL, etc).
> - Create custom reports against any Oracle database.
> - Create charts in SVG format.
> - Export data to CSV, EXCEL or XML versions of reports.
> - Create and edit HTML reports using a simple web UI (includes WYSIWYG    editor support).

Comment: "nice answer", hope you don't mind I added AbitMORE details about Forena (via a separate answer), to explain HOW to use these features.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/2360187 or http://forenasolutions.org/reports/help.setup  check for  Video demos and tutorials,details

Comment: thanks for recommending my community docu, and the docu that comes with the module!

Answer (score 0):

Try out this module. https://www.drupal.org/project/pdf_using_mpdf

```
API Function : pdf_using_mpdf_api()

      This API function is available to content developers that prefer to generate a pdf file of custom path. The function takes two parameters, first a rendered html content and an optional second parameter, name of the pdf file. E.g: pdf_using_mpdf_api($html) where $html is any html content.
```

The module provides API to create pdf for your custom pages, in order to create pdf without pager you can make pager conditional passing a url .parameter or you can have two pages one without pager to create PDF from

Answer (score 0):

## Module Forena

You could use the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module (disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of it) as your 1-stop-solution (using only 1 contributed module) to:

- Build your custom query to fetch the data, whereas these data can be retrieved directly from an external database such as Oracle.
- Format the look and feel of your results (the report) using xHTML (and/or charts if you'd like).
- Download the results in any of the typical formats, such as PDF, XLS, CSV, XML, JSON, etc.

To get an idea how its **Custom Queries** (SQLs) and/or **Report Specifications** look like, refer to the example in my answer to the question "[How to retrieve data directly from a Drupal database](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/166).".

The Forena [Video demos and tutorials](https://www.drupal.org/node/2360187) contain quite some links to live demos.

## Download options

For any report that you create (using [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena)), just add `.csv` as an extention to the report (output) URL. That contains the CSV equivalent of that report.

As a sample, consider the sample report located at `/reports/sample.states` (in your own site, one of the samples shipped with Forena). Change the URL to `/reports/sample.states.csv` (= just add `.csv` to it) to get the same report in `.csv` format. By adding such `.csv` to the URL of the [Simple Table of States in the demo site](http://forenasolutions.org/reports/sample.states), the result is [like so](http://forenasolutions.org/reports/sample.states.csv) ...

Same technique applies for other supported extensions (export formats), such as:

- [the PDF version](http://forenasolutions.org/reports/sample.states.pdf).
- [the HTML version](http://forenasolutions.org/reports/sample.states.html).
- [the XLS (MS Excell) version](http://forenasolutions.org/reports/sample.states.xls).
- [the DOC (MS Word) version](http://forenasolutions.org/reports/sample.states.doc).
- ... there are more.

Moreover, when building a report, you can also specify for which of these [Document Types](http://forenasolutions.org/reports/help.reportingwysiwyg#doctypes) an hyperlink should be made available in the report.

## Direct access to data blocks

All [data blocks](http://forenasolutions.org/reports/help.reportingwysiwyg#datablocks) are also accessible directly via their url, provided you have permission to access that block. Here are a few samples of that, for the sample report located at `/reports/sample.states`:

- in [XML format](http://forenasolutions.org/forena/xml/sampledb.states) (from the demo site).
- in [JSON format](http://forenasolutions.org/forena/json/sampledb.states) (from the demo site).

Answer (score 0):

```
$link_download = l(t('Download Report'), 'path/to/report/export'); 

function custom_menu(){ 
  $item['path/to/report/export'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'custom_report_export', 
    'title' => 'Data Export',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK, 
  ); 
  return $item;  
}


function custom_report_export() {
  $file = "report_name.xls";
  $table = callback_to_generate_theme_table_output_of_query_result();
  header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
  echo $table;
}
```