# How to handle complex test results?

Tags: 7, files

Actually we are using D7 mostly for books and book pages like manuals.

We would like to link files like PDF and Excel to a Drupal book page but we have no experience how to manage to open those files from drupal or view their content in drupal.

Therefore I would appreciate instructions for eventually necessary modules and settings.

We have a browser extension in chrome for PDF and see them directly in the browser , but from a Drupal page (localhost:8080/drupal/?q=it/node/398`), the link to that PDF first gets me to another page (`drupal/?q=media/1242`) and I have to click again on the PDF icon to open it in the browser. Thaty's somewhat annoying.
Can anyone please indicate a direct way for PDF and for Excel files? Is it necessary to fit the browser for Excel? if yes, how?

Comment: What do you mean by "handle complex test results" exactly? Do you mean provide forms for data entry? That's something Drupal will do easily, you can create a content type for the results and add as many nodes as you want. Attaching a file to a node is also built in to core, so you'll have no problems there either. Displaying an xls(x) in the browser is something you'll need a browser extension for, not something Drupal or any website would be able to help you with.

Comment: Thanks Clive. Well, with complex I meant great flexibility like Excel or a big data entry form. If there is already one I would try it. I have only little experience and tried just to set uo a new content type with a little bit of new fields to give it a strucutre, but I found it rather annoying to do for several fields. However if that's the only way...

Comment: As for the attached files, my browser wouldnt' tell me if I needed an extension, so how can i be sure the other users know what to do?
I have a browser extension for pdf and see them directly in my browser Chrome, but from drupal (http://localhost:8080/drupal/?q=it/node/398), the link to that pdf first gets me to another page: drupal/?q=media/1242 and I have to clic again on the pdf icon to open it in the browser. Can you please indicate a direct way either for pdf or for excel?
Michael

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "*... save the differences in an Excel table ...*", you might want to consider saving these data in an external database (MS SQL, MySql, Oracle, some PDO compliant database, etc).

And then use the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module to build custom queries to retrieve the data (directly from such database) and create custom reports from them. Those reports can then be exported in PDF or Excel. For that you just have to enable the desired Forena report options called "document format".

Refer to my answer to "[How to download Database results as PDF or in EXCEL](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/173813/how-to-download-database-results-as-pdf-or-in-excel/173851#173851)" for more details.

Comment: I will check it out, thank you, but still we often need to attach exisiting files to a node like pdf, word or excel for other purposes. is there a nice way to open those files from drupal someone can explain, please?